# Why is my laptop charging brick making high pitched whine that switches between two frequencies?

Tags: power-supply, charger

I have a laptop + charger that is getting on in years (~7 by now), and I just noticed that the charging brick is making a *very* faint high pitched whine. It alternates between two different frequencies that are fairly close together, and **I'm curious about why that's happening, rather than a steady single pitch.** (for reference, this is a 120W NSW25775 HSTNN-LA25 series charger)

Below, you can see a screenshot (sorry for the arrow in the middle left, I can't seem to manage to have it not visible) of a spectrogram that I produced on my phone from the audio of the noise.
[image: spectrogram of the noise, with visible lines at 3, 4.5, 6, and 9 kHz, suggesting a root frequency of 1.5 kHz, alternating to a slightly lower pitch where each tone lasts 1 second]

Some things that I've noted:

1. While it's mostly lost among the lower pitched noise, the series of visible tones (3 kHz, 4.5 kHz, 6 kHz, 9 kHz, etc) suggest to me a **fundamental frequency of 1.5 kHz** for the whine, modulating to a slightly lower tone.
2. The noise switches between the higher and lower pitch, as can be seen, where each tone lasts for approximately 1 second, for a **total period of 2 seconds.**

---

**What could be causing this switching between two different frequencies in such a regular fashion?** This occurs whether or not the charger is under load; as long as it's plugged in it will make the faint noise.

Comment: If you look at the laptop, does it have a LED blinking at the same rate when the pitch changes? The power/sleep LED for instance?

Comment: @Justme this happens even when not plugged into the laptop, only the wall

Comment: There isn't any way to know without some circuit information. The 'whine' is most likely caused by an SMPS switching circuit and is usually the inductor.

Comment: @VoltageSpike so would you suggest that it's likely something like a 50% duty cycle in the switching power supply?  Thanks for that term, it's a new one for me.

Comment: Is there any difference if you unplug it to run on battery for a while and then plug it in again? Does the noise disappear while the battery is charging?

Comment: Inductors and Ceramic caps can cause audible vibration when used in certain circuits like DC/DC converters and charge pumps. Sometimes this can be a signal of a component starting to degrade under high ripple current.

Comment: I have seen this many times at a very low audio level. It is something resonating in the power supply at the switching frequency or a harmonic thereof. Raising the switching frequency helps to eliminate this noise as well as improve efficiency and reduce size.